# make popover on a fixed position

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, popover

I using bootstrap v4.3.1, now the popover works fine but when the user scrolling the popover position goes down and I want to make it fixed on the top.

I try to override the style but still not working!

```
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        placement: 'top',
        html: true,
        title: 'test <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>',
        content: '<div class="media"><a href="#" class="pull-left"></a><div class="media-body"><p>test.</p></div></div>'
    });
    $(document).on("click", ".popover .close", function () {
        $(this).parents(".popover").popover('hide');
    });
```

```
   <a data-toggle="popover">
        <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `position:absolute` is added to the popover inline... we have to use !important to override it;

**working snippet** below:

```js
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
  placement: 'top',
  html: true,
  title: 'Test title <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>',
  content: '<div class="media"><a href="#" class="pull-left"></a><div class="media-body"><p>test description</p></div></div>'
});
$(document).on("click", ".popover .close", function() {
  $(this).parents(".popover").popover('hide');
});
```

```css
.popover.show {
  position: fixed !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a data-toggle="popover">
  <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
<h2> Right hand zone (6 col at the start) </h2>
I am using Bootstrap 4. I have a simple two column layout. The right column has a table of contents, the left column has a lot of markup with paragraphs, lists, images, and so on. I would like the content of the left column to use the whole width (of
both columns) where the table of contents (which takes less vertical space) ends. Like wrapping around an image except this is wrapping around a with lots of stuff inside. Is this possible (whether or not you think its a good idea?)</div>

<h1>Continued text (6 col at the start and then all width) </h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit... What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
  took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
  sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it? Where can I get some? There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available,
  but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden
  in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model
  sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
<h3>continuing...</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...Where does it come from? Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard
  McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable
  source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first
  line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum"
  by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
<h3>continuing further...</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit... It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
  distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will
  uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
```